# How can I program n steps where each step is a dataframe created from the previous step?

Tags: r, dataframe

I try to simulate changes in a data frame through different steps depending on each others. Let's try to take a very simple example to illustrate my problem.

I create a dataframe with two columns

```
a=runif(10)
b=runif(10)
data_1=data.frame(a,b)
data_1
            a          b
1  0.94922669 0.47418098
2  0.26702201 0.79179699
3  0.57398333 0.25158378
4  0.52724079 0.61531202
5  0.03999831 0.95233479
6  0.15171673 0.64564561
7  0.51353129 0.75676464
8  0.60312432 0.85318316
9  0.52900913 0.06297818
10 0.75459362 0.40209925
```

Then, I would like to create n steps, where each step consists in creating a new dataframe at i+1 which is function (let's call it "whatever") of the dataframe at i: data_2 is a transformation of data_1, data_3 a transformation of data_2, etc.

```
iterations=function(nsteps)
{
  lapply(1:nsteps,function(i)
  {  
  data_i+1=whatever(data_i)
  })

}
```

Whatever the function I use, I have an error message saying:

```
Error in whatever(data_i) : object 'data_i' not found
```

Can someone help me figure out what I am missing?

Comment: I think the error message tells you: you haven't defined `data_i` before you use it. Try initializing it by setting `data_i = 0` before iterating (or at the appropriate place). Also, I don't think you can have `data_i+1` set as a variable in `R`. I think you meant to have the `+1` on the other side of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can get some inspiration from the following example.
First, a `whatever` function to be applied to the previous dataframe.

```
whatever <- function(DF) {
  DF[[2]] <- DF[[2]]*2
  DF
}
```

Now the function you want. I have added an extra argument, the dataframe `x`.
The function starts by creating the object to be returned. Each member of the list `data_list` will be a dataframe function of the previous dataframe.

```
iterations <- function(nsteps, x){
  data_list <- vector("list", length = nsteps)
  data_list[[1]] <- x
  for(i in seq_len(nsteps)[-1]){
    data_list[[i]] <- whatever(data_list[[i - 1]])
  }
  names(data_list) <- sprintf("data_%d", seq_len(nsteps))
  data_list
}
```

And apply `iterations` to an example dataframe.

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = letters[1:10], X = 1:10)

iterations(10, df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a combination of `assign` and `paste`:

```
assign(paste("data_", i + 1, sep = ""), whatever(data_i))
```